# Who is "R. Drabek"?

Tags: math-history, mathematicians

The book "Algebra für Einsteiger" bei Bewersdorff (I think the English edition is called "Galois Theory for Beginners") starts with a nice quotation:

> Math is like love; a simple idea,
>   but it can get complicated.

This is attributed to "R. Drabek" who is not mentioned in the rest of the book.  If I google this name, I only find the above quotation again.  (I know there's a mathematician called Pavel Drábek, but I guess these two aren't the same.)

Does anyone have more information?

Comment: [Ask the author](http://bewersdorff-online.de/) (e-mail at the bottom) sounds like the best way to get more information here.

Comment: It is also attributed to G. Pólya, and P. Drábek has worked on Hardy-Pólya-type inequalities. Just another track to follow

Comment: Please, consider the possibility of a very simple typo...